# C++ segmentation fault with fgets (large file, large malloc)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am scanning a large dump file of coordinates 'out.dump' (~ 9GB) and keep getting a segfault on a line where I use `fgets()`. I read the file line by line and store it in an array called `lines[]`. Then, I `fscanf()` `lines[]` and store it in a pointer array called `cells[]`.

So far so good, but segfaults arise when I have a larger pointer array called `blocks[]`...Both cells and blocks only contain integers and I've used malloc so that both are on the heap. I'm not sure why I keep getting segfaults. Gdb and valgrind both tell me the error comes from the line I use `fgets()`, but I do not understand why...I've tried running the below code on multiple ubuntu machines and my macbook pro(m1, 32gb CPU).

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cmath>

#define Side 10
#define N 40
#define D 32
#define Steps 100000
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    double cell_inv=double (D)/Side;
    int cl = 2*D;
    int *blocks = (int*)malloc((cl*cl-2*cl+1)*Steps*sizeof(int));
    
    if (blocks==NULL){
        printf("mem alloc failed\n");
    }
    
    printf("%i\n", blocks[0]); //all of these print out fine
    blocks[0]=1; //prints fine
    printf("%i\n", blocks[0]); //prints fine
    
    
    int *cells = (int*)malloc(cl*cl * sizeof(int));
    FILE *dp;
    dp = fopen("./out.dump", "r");
    char lines[200];
    
    int *tr;
    double *x, *y;
    x = (double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    y = (double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    
    long int t=0;//keeps track of how much I am looping through
    int row,col;
    
    while(fgets(lines, 200, dp)!=NULL){ //segfault here when t=241 on terminal, t=2374 valgrind
        for (int i=0; i<cl; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<cl; j++){
                cells[cl*i+j]=0;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
            fgets(lines, 200, dp);
        } //ignoring first 8+1 lines of dump file
        
        for (int n=0; n < N; n++){
            fgets(lines, 200, dp);
            printf("%s\n", lines);
            sscanf(lines, "%i %i %lf %lf", tr, tr, &x[n], &y[n]);
        }
        
        for (int n=0; n < N; n++){
            row=int ((y[n]+Side)*cell_inv);
            col=int ((x[n]+Side)*cell_inv);
            cells[cl*row+col]=1;
        }
        
        printf("%li\n", t);
        t++;
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I ran a similar version of the code where I had `#define Steps 10000` instead where it compiled and ran without any error. So, I thought maybe the code made the arrays too large. But, I still don't get why there would be a limit to this if all my big arrays are on the heap...Also the memory allocations are not failing either.

I originally ran the debugger with the lines of code where I assigned values to different 'elements' of blocks e.g. `blocks[(cl-1) * Steps * i` *`+`*`Steps * j + t]=1;`In this case, these lines were where the segfaults occurred. I am not sure how to interpret my error messages form valgrind since they look like this:

```
==17599== 1 errors in context 2 of 10:
==17599== Invalid read of size 8
==17599==    at 0x5245B06: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
==17599==    by 0x108AC0: main (play.cpp:45)
==17599==  Address 0x9 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Line 45 is the line where I used fgets indicated above.

Comment: The only C++ things I see is `#include <string>` and `#include <cmath>` but I don't see that you are using anything from those. Did you mean to make this a C program but mixed in some C++ headers by mistake? Everything screams "C" about this program.

Comment: Calculate the array sizes, store them in variables, and show the values. That way you can see if the size calculations are overflowing.

Comment: Later on, when outputting files I use iostream/ifstream but I suppressed that part in the code above.

Comment: Ok, the part we do see is done in a very "C" style way and one concern is that you do not seem to care about if many of the `fgets` and `scanf`s you call fails or not.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not sure what you mean by the size calculations overflowing...My biggest (pointer) array blocks should contain 396900000 elements. Is it possible that simply calculating the required indices for this array is causing segfaults?

Comment: `int *blocks = (int*)malloc((cl*cl-2*cl+1)*Steps*sizeof(int));` -- Are you running a 32-bit program or a 64-bit program?  What is the value of the number of bytes you are allocating?  From the looks of things, your program is 32-bit, since the pointer values are 32-bits wide.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried checking if the scans failed or not by printing out my lines[] after each fgets. They all print out as expected until the segfault occurs, so I was assuming the sscanf would also work as I want it to up to that point.

Comment: You check if `sscanf` and `fgets` succeed by checking their return values. `sscanf(lines, "%i %i %lf %lf", tr, tr, &x[n], &y[n])` should return 4, otherwise it failed to extract all 4 values from the string etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm pretty sure I am running a 64-bit program. Also, I am not sure how to check the size of the memory I am allocating to each pointer array...

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: `sizeof(int *)` -- What is the value?  If it's 4, then you are running a 32-bit program.  I am looking at this: `at 0x5245B06: fgets (iofgets.c:47)`, and that pointer value suggests 32-bit.  Usually a debugger would show 16 hex digits for a 64-bit pointer value, not 8 hex digits.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I get the following output when I use the file command             ./play.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)....

Comment: @MinJaeKim — is that the value that the program actually calculated? When code doesn’t work right, describing what you **think** it does isn’t the same as looking at what it **actually** does.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Checking, sscanf does pick up 4 values every time. I am not as familiar with using string and vector, which is why I'm writing my code like above. Also, I wasn't sure if using these would increase the memory I need/slow down my code.

Comment: `int *tr;` - you never initialise `tr`.  But you do subsequently pass it to `sscanf`.  After that, all bets are off.

Comment: If you had used C++ streams, std::vector, and std::string, you would never had encountered the issue brought up by @PaulSanders.  It seems you are falling back to writing C code, not C++.

Comment: @PaulSanders I thought I was assigning a value to tr by using sscanf. These were values that I was trying to throw away. So. would the problem be solved if I just initialise tr to any value and then start feeding it these throwaway values from my file?

Comment: @MinJaeKim Why is `tr` a pointer?  Why isn't it just an `int tr;`, thus provide `sscanf` with `&tr`?  A function can do nothing with an uninitialized pointer, unless the function takes a pointer to the pointer, or a reference to the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

One bug in the program is here:

```
int * tr;

[...]
sscanf(lines, "%i %i %lf %lf", tr, tr, &x[n], &y[n]);
```

Note that in the above code, `sscanf()` is writing integers through an uninitialized pointer, which invokes undefined behavior and (on my Mac, anyway) causes a crash.

I was able to avoid the fault by changing the code to this instead:

```
int tr;

[...]
sscanf(lines, "%i %i %lf %lf", &tr, &tr, &x[n], &y[n]);
```

.... Note that because `&tr` is passed to `sscanf()` twice in one call, the variable `tr` will be written to twice by that call, and it isn't obvious whether after `sscanf()` returns, `tr` will be the first value parsed from the line or the second one.  Since the program never uses `tr`'s value for anything anyway, that doesn't really matter, but if/when you do decide to use the first two columns of your data file, you'll probably want to pass in pointers to two different variables instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! The second version of the code was actually the one I originally had, but I changed tr to a pointer just to see if that would change anything. It didn't cause any crashes for my machine, but good to know that that could cause a issue!